# Crash during startup with network share for gitlab container

Tags: docker, gitlab

Following the [documentation](http://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/), I am trying to setup my own gitlab using the docker container.

In the volumes section, the host path /srv/gitlab is a network share.

I have a group with name docker and the current user belongs to that group.  While mounting the network share, I specified the uid=,gid=docker.

My problem is, the docker container starts but keeps crashing with some permission error.  I am pretty sure its because of the network share.

Anyone has any idea on setting correct permissions for the network share before starting the gitlab container?

This is how the error looks like:

```
[2016-09-07T23:18:49+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2016-09-07T23:18:49+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2016-09-07T23:18:49+00:00] ERROR: directory[/etc/gitlab] (gitlab::default line 26) had an error: Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ chown_internal - /etc/gitlab
[2016-09-07T23:18:49+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: did you try run it with ```sudo``` ?

Comment: Yes.  I tried. The container runs as long as the page is not accessed.  Once accessed, it crashes with same error.